# Unity Networked Ready check

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

Trying to create a ready check using PUN2 so that all players will load into the game scene at the same time, but I do not understand how to check another players custom property and keep a count of how many players are currently ready and if all are ready then start the game. I think I have a custom property set up for every player that should be but I am unsure if it working at all.

```
 public class HeroSelectController : MonoBehaviour
 {
     [HideInInspector]
     public string selectedHero;

     private PhotonView PV;
     private bool PlayerReady = false;
     private ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable _playerCustomProperties = new ExitGames.Client.Photon.Hashtable();

     private void Update()
     {
         Debug.Log("Player Ready = " + _playerCustomProperties["PlayerReady"]);
     }

     private void HeroSelect()
     {
         PlayerReady = true;    
         selectedHero = "PlayerTest";
         PhotonNetwork.SetPlayerCustomProperties(_playerCustomProperties);
         _playerCustomProperties["PlayerReady"] = PlayerReady;
     }

     public void OnClickHeroButton()
     {
         HeroSelect();

         if (PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient)
         {
             foreach (var photonPlayer in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
             {
                 photonPlayer.CustomProperties["PlayerReady"] = true;
                 PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(3);
             }
         }

     }
 }
```

What is currently happening is that the master client can start the game regardless of everyone else's state. Feel like I might be overthinking all of this and there is a much similar solution as I would expect a function like this to be common place as I would expect something similar to be used in many online games so if I am going about completely the wrong way please point me a more suitable direction

Comment: Well currently your master client simply sets all players to ready and loads the scene.. maybe you should use some kind of check instead?

Comment: @derHugo thats exactly what I want just unsure as to how to do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't know exactly how Photon works but I assume these properties are already synchronized and as far as I understand you simply want some kind of a check like e.g.

```
private bool AllPlayersReady
{
    get
    {
        foreach (var photonPlayer in PhotonNetwork.PlayerList)
        {
            if(photonPlayer.CustomProperties["PlayerReady"] == false) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Which you could probably also shorten using Linq like

```
using System.Linq;

...

private bool AllPlayersReady => PhotonNetwork.PlayerList.All(player => player.CustomProperties["PlayerReady"] == true);
```

And then use it like

```
public void OnClickHeroButton()
 {
     HeroSelect();

     if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

     if(!AllPlayersReady)
     {
         return;
     }


     PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(3);
 }
```

---

This can still be enhanced since now the master has to press repeatedly until maybe everyone is ready. I would additionally use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) like

```
public void OnClickHeroButton()
{
     HeroSelect();

     if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

     StartCoroutine (WaitAllReady ());   
 }

 private IEnumerator WaitAllReady()
 {
     yield return new WaitUntil (() => AllPlayersReady);

     PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(3);
 }
```

---

Thanks to Iggy:

Instead of a routine which checks every frame you can use [`OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate`](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state#custom_properties) in order to check for the ready state

```
void OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate(Player targetPlayer, Hashtable changedProps)
{
    if (!PhotonNetwork.IsMasterClient) return;

    // you can even limit the check to make it 
    // only if "PlayerReady" is among the changed properties
    if(!changedProps.Contains("PlayerReady")) return;

    if(!AllPlayersReady) return;

    PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel(3);
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: @JoshuaDavidson please note that I made `AllPlayersReady` a property not a method ;) you might also be interested in the update adding a Coroutine for waiting until all are ready instead of having to click repeatedly

Comment: Instead of checking custom properties every frame you can listen for one of the callbacks that PUN provides `OnRoomPropertiesUpdate` & `OnPlayerPropertiesUpdate`. Scroll down to [Custom Properties](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/gameplay/synchronization-and-state).

Comment: @derHugo is there something I am missing, I am tying to do exactly this but I am getting a error on the  "private bool AllPlayersReady()" error it "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Apparently `CustomProperties` is a `Hashtable` .. you probably have to explicitly use either `player.CustomProperties["PlayerReady"] == true` again or cast it like `(bool)player.CustomProperties["PlayerReady"]`

Comment: changedProps.Contains must be changed to changedProps.ContainsKey